# Why does a tub spout leak

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathtub, valve

Why does a tub spout leak. Brand new combo shower tub valve and tub spout. Will slowly leak over a few days before completely dries out, about a tablespoon. The plumber came back and replaced the cartridge which did not stop the  leak and did not know what else to do. Is this normal? The water here is very hard, if left unattended for any length of time the tub will stain. Is this excess water left over from the shower? Why would it take such a long time to drain and why doesn't the tub spout diverter hold the water?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you post a picture of the spout and controls, as well as the brand name and model?

Comment: It could be left over from the shower. If the diverrter is turned from shower to spout, then whatever water was left in the pipe to the shower head, will slowly drain back to the spout.